# Where is "~/.config/nvim/init.vim" on Windows?

Tags: neovim, microsoft-windows, init

I just download Neovim & I'm trying to configure it following a tutorial, but I
can't find the path `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/nvim/init.vim`  or
`~/AppData/Local/nvim/init.vim`. I don't know if a have to enter from CMD or
from windows powershell. I've doing research but nothing is clear enough,
although I'm lacking some knowledge.

I used chocolatey to install, and the folders I have look like this:

- `C:\tools\neovim\Neovim`

  - inside of this there are 3 folders, `bin`, `lib` & `share`
- `C:\Users\nameUser\AppData\Local\nvim-data`

  - 1 folder `shada` & a log file

Inside of `local` there isn't a `nvim` folder; it's not hidden or something, I
checked.

`:echoerr "init.vim is loaded"` shows `init.vim is loaded`

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! Just a quick note: the `:echoerr` test doesn't really mean anything; `:echoerr` just echo's what you type (no actual checking anything) with error highlighting. Probably the simplest thing do to (assuming you're on windows) is launch neovim and type `:edit ~/AppData/Local/nvim/init.vim`--you might have to create the `nvim` directory (it looks like the rest is already there)

Comment: Thanks! Now iI have another problem when add this 3 lines on init.vim
**set runtimepath^=~/.vim runtimepath+=~/.vim/after
let &packpath = &runtimepath
source ~/.vimrc**
and open nvim gives me an error in the last one, I try creating .vimrc in the same directory but still shows that errorError detected while processing C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\nvim\init.vim:
line    3:
E484: Can't open file C:\Users\username/.vimrc
Press ENTER or type command to continue

Comment: i’ll add a short answer covering my comment. If you have new questions, you may ask new ones; do note that some of your questions may already have answers (and we appreciate your efforts to do some research first )

Answer (score 8):

It is likely that you are reading the wrong tutorial since you are using Windows, but your tutorial are apparently meant for Linux/macOS users.

The definitive answer: the neovim config is named `init.vim` or `init.lua` and its location varies based on the operating system you use. You can use command `:echo stdpath('config')` inside Neovim to find this directory. If this directory does not exist, just create it and put your config file in it. That is all.

See also neovim's doc on [startup](https://neovim.io/doc/user/starting.html#startup) and doc on [stdpath()](https://neovim.io/doc/user/eval.html#stdpath()).

Answer (score 1):

The `:echoerr` test doesn't really mean anything; `:echoerr` just echo's what you type (no actual checking anything) with error highlighting.

Probably the simplest thing do to (assuming you're on windows) is launch neovim and type `:edit ~/AppData/Local/nvim/init.vim`--you might have to create the nvim directory (it looks like the rest is already there).

I don't know the appropriate windows commands, but on a *nix, you would do

```
mkdir ~/.config/nvim
nvim ~/.config/nvim/init.vim
```

(assuming `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME` is `~/.config` or unset)